# Using Bash Script to feed input to command line

Tags: linux, bash

So I am trying to make a bash script that calls this one command and then feeds it the input. It calls this one command and the command needs 3-4 inputs after. I type the command and it waits for me to enter first name, one I enter first name it waits for me to enter last name, and so on. How can I use bash script to pass these arguments to the command one at a time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A couple of ways.

Group all the echo commands and pipe them to the command:

```
{ echo $firstname; echo $lastname ; } | somecommand
```

or use a heredoc:

```
somecommand <<EOF
$firstname
$lastname
EOF
```

Comment: If I use the piping method. Would it pipe them one a time tho? As I need it give it one input and then it asks me for another one after. I can't just give them all the inputs in a single input if that makes sense

Comment: Both of them send each input as a separate line. `echo` adds a newline by default.

Comment: @Barmar Why the `()` subshell?  I think a `{}` command grouping should suffice here without the need for an extra fork()?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much difference, since it has to fork for the pipe.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't seem to be working. So I have two variables firstname="John" lastname="Smith" and a variable command. When I do (echo $firstname echo $lastname) | $command it executes the command but then it sits waiting for me to enter first name

Comment: Unless the command is reading from `/dev/tty` instead of standard input, I don't know why it would do that.

Comment: If it makes a difference the command is openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privkey.pem -out cacert.pem -x509 
-new     -days 1095

Comment: What happens if you do `command < /dev/null`? Does it wait for input as well?

Comment: Yes it still waits for input

Comment: Then it must be reading from the terminal instead of standard input. You may have to write an Expect script to resolve this.