# Bash script type inputs when prompted

Tags: linux, bash, shell, input, stdin

**EDIT**: I'm re-writing this because the first time was a bit unclear.

Let's say I have a program (an executable) such that when I run it, it prompts me to enter an input.

For example, I execute `./myProgram`

and the program prompts: `Please enter your username:`

Here, I would type in my username.

Now, how would I write a bash script so that after I start the above program, I can enter inputs to it?

Something along the lines of this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path/to/myProgram

# And here I would enter the commands, such as providing my username
```

Thanks

Comment: `read -p 'Please enter your username: ' u`

Comment: You need `expect` for that, well, that's the easy way to do it anyway

Comment: If your script starts an interactive program, that interactive program still has I/O access to the terminal where you started the script. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Or do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174849/using-bash-script-to-feed-input-to-command-line

Comment: Yes, I mean the second one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Bash Script to feed input to command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174849/using-bash-script-to-feed-input-to-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

`read`ing values interactively is rather uncommon in *nix scripts, and is frowned upon by those who want to do exactly what you're trying to do. The standard way of doing this would be **changing `myProgram` to accept [arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).** At that point it's trivial to do this.

If you really need to use this pattern you need to use some tool like `expect`, [as pointed out by @EricRenouf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253946/bash-script-type-inputs-when-prompted/34254869#comment56250257_34253946).

Answer (score 0):

If `myProgram` reads from standard input, you can use a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

```
path/to/myProgram <<\END
username
more input if needed
END
```