# Run command with multiple input parameters

Tags: dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18 and trying to install PHP using command

```
apt-get install -y php
```

But during installation, It asks for geographic area and city, so I need to manually input these 2 things.

Since I am preparing commands for Dockerfile, so I am trying to mention all inputs in command itself but not getting way, so is there any way that I can append multiple inputs to my command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Bash Script to feed input to command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174849/using-bash-script-to-feed-input-to-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your Dockerfile

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

[Here's the link where i find the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331836/apt-get-install-tzdata-noninteractive)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below command for installing PHP:

`sudo apt install php`

As far as I know, running with sudo may help u in installing php easily.

Comment: I am already inside my sudo user, I used Sudo su then installing PHP

Comment: Ok, then you go with above approach, setting debian frontend to non-interactive